# Is it possible to convert a Tandy 1000 EX video signal to SCART?

Tags: cga, tandy-1000, scart

I've recently acquired a Tandy 1000 EX. It appears to have a 9 pin RGB video out and I understand it produces a CGA signal. I would like to connect this output to my SCART switcher, which is connected to my Sony PVM via RGB+sync cable. Is it possible to convert the output from the Tandy 1000 EX to SCART?

I found this active converter:

https://www.serdashop.com/CGA2SCART-PRO

Seems like this might work, but I'm not 100% sure. So far my research leads me to believe there is nothing passive that will convert the signal to SCART.

Comment: You are aware that SCART is not a single interface to be converted to, but a plug carrying various alternate interface? You may need to specify which of them you need - eventually the one the CRT to be used expects.

Comment: I think that CGA2SCART device would work connected to an appropriate SCART to Sony PVM monitor cable. You are just converting digital RGBI to analog RGB. I don't do this myself because my PVM includes the RGBI input, as well as the analog RGB.

Comment: Related question: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-can-i-adapt-a-digital-cga-c128-signal-rgbi-de-9-to-a-modern-monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that a 1 to 1 mapping between RGB (CGA) connectors and SCART is not possible and therefore passive adapters are not available. There are open-source schematics to help make this conversion, such as this one:

https://www.electroschematics.com/cga-scart-adapter/

However, it's my understanding that this does not 100% accurately map colors.

Ultimately I decided to purchase the CGA2SCART PRO device previously mentioned. It claims to handle proper mapping of color ("brown fix") and I don't have to soldier, so that's a bonus.